# Autopopulate from Select box from database

Tags: php, mysql

hope you can help, please forgive any poor coding or anytihng, I'm new to this and just hacking my way through to get things to work.

That said, on one of my projects I have this code, which successfully populates the dropdown from a database when the page is loaded:

```
<select name="Region" id="Region">
    <option value="">-- Select Region --</option>
    <?php                     
       $region=$POST['Region'];    
       if ($region); {
            $regionquery = "SELECT DISTINCT REGION FROM Sales_Execs ";    
            $regionresult = mysql_query($regionquery);    
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($regionresult)) {
                echo "<option value=\"".$row['REGION']."\">".$row['REGION']."</option>\n  ";
            }       
       }
     ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('Region').value = <?php echo json_encode(trim($_POST['Region']));?>;
        </script>
    </select>
```

On my next project that I'm working on now, I need to do the same thing, so I copied the above code amended, and placed in my new project:

```
<select name="Sales_Exec" id="Sales_Exec">    
<option value="">-- Select SE --</option>
<?php                     
   $salesexec=$POST['Sales_Exec'];    
   if ($salesexec);    
   {
       $salesexecquery = "SELECT DISTINCT Assigned FROM Data ";    
       $salesexecresult = mysql_query($salesexecquery);    
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($salesexecresult))
       {
            echo "<option value=\"".$row['ASSIGNED']."\">".$row['ASSIGNED']."</option>\n  ";
        }       
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('Sales_Exec').value = <?php echo json_encode(trim($_POST['Sales_Exec']));?>;
</script>

</select>
```

This second chunk of code doesn't work... and I can't work out why as it seems I've copied it all and amended all the neccersary parts, can anyone spot what is wrong?

Thankyou!

Comment: any error messages?  are you really missing the initial < ?

Comment: Does the select get populated or does it just have empty values as I guess - because you fetch `Assigned` from the database but you echo `ASSIGNED` (case matters!)

Comment: It doesn't get populated at all, just the initial --Select Sales Exec--- appears with no other options, blank or otherwise.  Will try amending the case tho.  No Error messages at all.

Comment: Another side note: You are building a heaven for XSS. I know you are just starting but try to follow the very basic security rules from the beginning. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: Is that code **completely** the same as you have it working? I see multiple strange things like `if ($salesexec);` (why `;` after if?), $POST instead of $_POST

Comment: It's exactly the same, I copied it straight from the one that works, which I've tested again just now and works fine, confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `$salesexec` but it should be `$salesexec=$_POST['Sales_Exec'];` (note `$_POST` instead of `$POST`.

The field in the database is `Assigned` (only first letter uppercase), you are echo'ing `ASSIGNED` (all uppercase) which is not set.

Use

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row['Assigned']."\">".$row['Assigned']."</option>\n  ";
```

As for the XSS vulnerability, there is actually not even the need to set the value with JavaScript, check the `POST` within your loop and set the chosen value directly in the option:

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row['Assigned']."\"";
if (isset($_POST['Sales_Exec']) && $_POST['Sales_Exec'] == $row['Assigned']) { 
    echo ' SELECTED';
}
echo ">".$row['Assigned']."</option>\n  ";
```

Comment: This gives me the initial ---Select sales Exec --- and one blank option beneath it.  I amended the case on my initial effort to read Assigned, but that had no effect at all.  Wierd / Frustrating.

Comment: Take a look at the source code of the generated page. Any errors that your script might cause will be part of the `<select ...>` element and therefore not visible in the browser, but in the source code. Or just remove the first line of your script and see what it generates.

Comment: aha, looking at the page source, there IS an error :'<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Renewal Tool/Index.php</b> on line <b>96</b><br />'

Comment: Something is wrong with your query, wrong table name, wrong row name. replace `$salesexecresult = mysql_query($salesexecquery);` with `$salesexecresult = mysql_query($salesexecquery) || die(mysql_error());` to see what goes wrong.

Comment: It says No database selected... I've checked the name and the case of the DB and the table (there's only 1 table) and that's all correct, wierd.

Comment: The I guess you have some other settings missing in your script. Hotfix: Try adding the DB name to your query: `SELECT ... FROM DBNAME.Data ...`